# conditional for multiple events to trigger eventReactive in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a leaflet object in my Shiny app and I would like to show markers on the map when the user zooms past a certain level. I want this to happen based on two events:

1. user zooms on map OR
2. the bounds change while zoomed into the necessary threshold.

Here are my two reactive functions that are being used as the data argument for `addCircleMarkers`.

```
transIn <- reactive({
        bounds <- input$OrgMap_bounds
        latRng <- range(bounds$north, bounds$south)
        lngRng <- range(bounds$east, bounds$west)

        subset(org_input(),
               latitude >= latRng[1] & latitude <= latRng[2] &
                 longitude >= lngRng[1] & longitude <= lngRng[2])
      })

transInBounds <- eventReactive({input$OrgMap_zoom | input$OrgMap_bounds}, {
            if(as.integer(input$OrgMap_zoom) <= 5){
              return(orglevel[63,])
            } else {
                return(transIn())
                }
            })

observe({
leafletProxy("OrgMap", data = transInBounds()) %>% 
clearMarkers() %>% 
addCircleMarkers(~longitude, ~latitude, radius = 1, color = "red", fillOpacity = 1, popup = ~as.character(organization), group = "Locations")
})
```

I get the following error when running this code:

> Warning: Error in |: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.